# get-disk unmount one-liner needs and exception

Tags: powershell

I am mounting and unmounting all **GPT** filesystems on my server via **powershell**.  However, now I am asked can you unmount all the disks except Z.

My code is simple:

```
powershell.exe -command "Get-Disk | Where-Object PartitionStyle -eq 'GPT' | Set-Disk -IsOffline:$true"
```

How to I put in except Z into this one liner?

Comment: `Z` is a *drive* letter. A disk is not (necessarily) a drive

Answer (score 0):

you have to mind that a driveletter like "Z" referencing to a partition and not a disk. 
But the following should work:

```
Get-Disk | Where-Object PartitionStyle -eq 'GPT' | Where-Object {$_.Disknumber -ne ( Get-Partition -DriveLetter Z | get-disk).number}
```